# How can I specify property argument signature in interfaces using code first approach in nestjs?

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs

I'm using nestjs 7 and have been trying to set up an interface that contains a property with optional arguments. The issue I have been encountering is that the generated schema does not include the arguments for the interface itself, only for the types that implement this interface.

I tried implementing a bogus method on the interface itself, but that still doesn't include the args in the generated schema

Example

```js
@ArgsType()
export class CountArgs {
  @Field(type => GraphQLISODateTime, { nullable: true })
  start?: Date

  @Field(type => GraphQLISODateTime, { nullable: true })
  end?: Date
}

@InterfaceType()
export abstract class IObjectMetrics {
  @Field(type => Int)
  count(@Args() args: CountArgs): number {
    throw new Error('Method not implemented')
  }
}

@ObjectType({ implements: [IObjectMetrics] })
export class ObjectMetrics extends IObjectMetrics {} // implementing rather than extending makes no difference in the generated SDL

@Resolver(of => ObjectMetrics)
export abstract class ObjectMetricsResolver {
  @ResolveField(type => Int)
  count(@Args() args: CountArgs) {
    return getCountSomehow(args)
  }
}
```

The above results in the following schema:

```
interface IObjectMetrics {
  count: Int!
}

type ObjectMetrics implements IObjectMetrics {
  count(start: DateTime, end: DateTime): Int!
}
```

The problem with this is that I can't then create a fragment on the interface type and reuse it, since the interface doesn't contain the argument signature.
Is there any way to achieve this using the code first approach or am i stuck using schema first?

Comment: `@InputType()` ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you elaborate? Use @InputType() decorator instead of @ArgsType()?